# how to supply a value in redirectToAction to some other method using asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction

I want to supply a value in RedirectToAction() to some other method. My requirement is like this. I al registering a new user.On clicking the next button, I have to register the new user as well as to redirect to some other page with the registration details.So, here I have to supply value in RedirectToAction to get the registration details in new page.Can anyone help me in doing this??

My form is like this:-

New User Reg.:-
email 
password

```
Next
```

So, on clicking the next button, I can register the new user but I can't supply the value. How can I do this?? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In the next form, I have to get those registration details.I can get them but I can't first supply the value to that method.

Comment: u can use `Query String` as well,if agree to use it then i will tell you how to use `Query String` in MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass details by using `Query String` like

```
return this.RedirectToAction
  ("Actionname", new { yourvalue = "querystringvalue" });

it Would return:
/controller/Actionname?value1=querystringvalue
```

I am Assuming that there's no route parameter named `yourvalue`.

Hope you understand and works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use TempData. It uses session under the covers to preserve any information you need. Beware that once you read the data, TempData would be cleared. An example of using it would be:

```
TempData["MyKey"] = WhateEverYouWantSaved;
RedirectToAction ("Action","Controller");
```

In your action method:

```
Model m = TempData["MyKey"]; //Cast to Model type if need be
```

It has the advantage of not including your data in the URL which means less data going back and forth, less chance of the data exceeding URL maximum length, and if you don't want the user to see the data, that is pretty much your only option.